# mySQL exclude counted column if under

Tags: mysql, join, count, subquery

I am trying to find the sum of hours worked for each type of owner excluding services of employees who have an ExperienceLevel of 'Junior' and any ExperienceLevel type with less than 3 members. I have been working on this forever and cannot get the answer....

TABLES:

```
OWNER ( OwnerID, OwnerName, OwnerEmail, OwnerType )
PROPERTY ( PropertyID, PropertyName, Street, City, State, Zip, OwnerID )
EMPLOYEE ( EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, CellPhone, ExperienceLevel )
SERVICE ( PropertyID, EmployeeID, ServiceDate, HoursWorked )
```

My Latest QUERY:

```
SELECT OwnerType, SUM(HoursWorked) AS SumOfHoursWorked
 FROM EMPLOYEE, SERVICE, OWNER
 WHERE EMPLOYEE.EmployeeID = SERVICE.EmployeeID 
 AND EMPLOYEE.ExperienceLevel <> 'Junior'
 AND (SELECT COUNT(ExperienceLevel) > 2)
```

Comment: AND EMPLOYEE.ExperienceLevel IN(SELECT ExperienceLevel FROM Employee HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(ExperienceLevel))> 2)

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be join conditions between all of the tables in the select statement and you are only qualifying the join between employee and service.

In addition to

```
where employee.employeeid = service.employeeid
```

add

```
and service.propertyid = property.propertyId 
and property.ownerid = owner.ownerid
```

as Mihai,s comment suggested

```
and employee.experiencelevel in (select experiencelevel from employee having count(*) > 2)
```

finally, the sums will work better if the values are grouped.

```
group by ownertype;
```